# Display users who flagged content

Tags: views, users, flags

In my Drupal 7 project I have users of role `A` and `B` respectively. Users of role `A` can create content and users of role `B` can flag it.

I'm building a view that displays on `A` users' account page their content and names of `B` users who flaggd it.

I have created a view `Content` (not `User`) and added relationship `Flags: Content flag` and consequently field `Flags: User uid` to display together with content related fields.

In view block I use `Grid` format. Same content information is displayed several times per each user who flagged it, like  bellow

Content title **QWERTY**
Users uid  who flagged **1**

Content title **QWERTY**
Users uid who flagged **2**

Content title **QWERTY**
Users uid  who flagged **3**

How can I display content information only once and users who flagged in one field separated by comma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to **edit** /drupal/sites/all/themes/MYTHEMENAME/**template.php**

then add the following code.

```
function MYTHEMENAME_preprocess_views_view_fields($vars){
      if ($vars['view']->name == "VIEWNAME" && $vars['view']->current_display == "DISPLAY" && $vars['id'] != 1){
        $vars['fields']['title']->content = '';
      }
    }
```

**What this code is saying is if your row is not equal to (`!=`) 1, then don't display anything. Thus, it will print your title only for row 1.**

- replace MYTHEMENAME with your actual theme name.
- replace VIEWNAME with your view's name. example: flagged_content
- replace DISPLAY with your view's machine name. You can find this by editing your view, then under Advanced -> other

  examples: block, block_1, page, page_1 or default. It's default if you're using your master view.

For user's separated by comma you would have to use css for that.

[JS FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9n6Lv2a3/)

PS: I think you would have to change it from grid to html list for your view.